# How can I swap places of strings in a 2d string array

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I have homework to make a custom version of chess which is 6x6 and the pieces move in a specific way. But for now I am trying to figure out how to select a piece and then place it in another location inside the 2d array I have set up and swap the places of the characters. For now I have:

```
public class Chess {

    static final int rows = 7;
    static final int columns = 7;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] board = new String[rows][columns];
        fillBoard(board);
        enterMove();
    }
    public static void fillBoard(String[][] board){
        for (int row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
                board[row][col] = " X ";
                outerShell(board);
                pawns(board);
                System.out.print(board[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void outerShell(String[][] board){
        board[0][0] = "   ";
        board[0][1] = " A ";
        board[0][2] = " B ";
        board[0][3] = " C ";
        board[0][4] = " D ";
        board[0][5] = " E ";
        board[0][6] = " F ";
        board[1][0] = " 6 ";
        board[2][0] = " 5 ";
        board[3][0] = " 4 ";
        board[4][0] = " 3 ";
        board[5][0] = " 2 ";
        board[6][0] = " 1 ";
    }
    public static void pawns(String[][] board){
        //whitePawns
        board[1][1] = "wDw";
        board[1][2] = " wD";
        board[1][3] = " wQ";
        board[1][4] = " wK";
        board[1][5] = " wM";
        board[1][6] = " wDw ";
        //blackPawns
        board[6][1] = "bDw";
        board[6][2] = " bM";
        board[6][3] = " bK";
        board[6][4] = " bQ";
        board[6][5] = " bD";
        board[6][6] = " bDw";
    }
    public static void enterMove(){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Select the piece you want to move(Example a1) if you want to quit enter: q");
        Scanner gameInput  = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pieceSelect = gameInput.nextLine();
        if(pieceSelect.equals("q")){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        switch (pieceSelect){
            case "a1": 

        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Now select a finishing position for the piece to move to");
        String piecePlace = gameInput.nextLine();
        switch (piecePlace){
            case "a2": 
        }
    }
}
```

In the `enterMove()` section, I am trying to do it with `switch` but have no idea how to swap two positions in the array. I am not dead set on using `switch` because I am not sure if it is possible at all. If someone can make a version of this code where by entering the specific coordinates(like a1) selects `bDw` then entering another coordinate and swapping `bDw` with the `X` i am using as an indicator for an empty space and if possible to explain it i'd be grateful.

Comment: The thing is you need to keep track of the current positions of the pawns. For that, You might need to use a key value data structure like `Map` in Java.

Comment: Alternatively, you can take the initial position (x, y) and final position(x,y) as an input. And when you are done, you can say: "Moved xx from aa to bb".

Comment: Yes I am trying to do the second thing suggested but have no idea how to imploment it in code. For now I want with imputs to swap the piece inputed with the position of the X inputed which indicates in my program empty space. Later I will probably need to change things such as when a piece is selected over an enemy piece to delete it as in taking it and if a piece is inputed to go on a friendly piece to not be a valid move.

Comment: You can take an integer input twice from the user for initial position. i.e. One for x co-ordinate and one for y co-ordinate. Later you can use this value as board[x][y] to access or change the value of the board. You can copy the value of the pawn into another variable and set board[x][y] to empty string.  and set the value of board[a][b] with this var. where a,b are the final coordinates.

Comment: I am not sure I am really following you. I forgot to mention that I am not very experienced in programming so if you are so kind to dumb it down a bit and explain more in detail thanks... and sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a chess program before and I used to store all the pieces in an array(here in 6x6 array) and I used the index values as board coordinates.
So when a piece is selected a function is called to show the valid moves of the selected piece.

The valid moves can be stored in some array and can be checked. Then just swap the values within the array itself.